# How do I sum arbitrarily nested values with jq?

Tags: json, nested, sum, jq

I've been struggling to come up with a way to sum arbitrarily nested fields with `jq`. The level of "buckets" varies between calls (different levels of rollup fields). So how would I sum all the `avg_amount` fields in the following snippet (ideally without hardcoding each `.buckets.[]`)?

```
[
   {
      "buckets":[
         {
            "buckets":[
               {
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "avg_amount":25,
                     }
                  ],
                  "destination":"Apple"
               },
               {
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "avg_amount":74,
                     }
                  ],
                  "destination":"Google"
               }
            ],
            "vendor_name":"Vendor Bee"
         },
         {
            "buckets":[
               {
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "avg_amount":1000,
                     }
                  ],
                  "destination":""
               }
            ],
            "vendor_name":""
         }
      ],
      "company_id":1
   }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines -- i.e., indicate the expected answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fixing your JSON, the query:

```
jq '[.. | objects | .avg_amount] | add'
```

yields `1099`.

(This query is robust w.r.t. the existence of the key "avg_amount" as `add` handles `null` as 0.)

## hjson

If fixing the JSON manually is an issue, you could (for example) use `hjson -j`.  See https://hjson.org/